# Broken stl object after export

Tags: matlab, stl

for a couple of days I am trying to export an .stl object from Matlab.
I am using [stlwrite(filename, varargin)](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20922-stlwrite-filename--varargin-) function to export the object. Here is the code:

```
clear all, close all

K=0.9;     % try K from 0.7 to 1

c(1,:)=[-K -K -K];
c(2,:)=[-K +K -K];
c(3,:)=[-K -K +K];
c(4,:)=[-K +K +K];
c(5,:)=[+K -K -K];
c(6,:)=[+K +K -K];
c(7,:)=[+K -K +K];
c(8,:)=[+K +K +K];

x(1)=rand();        % random starting point
y(1)=rand(); 
z(1)=rand(); 

for j=1:40000  

    cc=c(ceil(8*rand()),:); 

    x(j+1) = cc(1) + (x(j)-cc(1))/((sqrt((x(j)-cc(1))^2+(y(j)-cc(2))^2+(z(j)-cc(3))^2))^2);
    y(j+1) = cc(2) + (y(j)-cc(2))/((sqrt((x(j)-cc(1))^2+(y(j)-cc(2))^2+(z(j)-cc(3))^2))^2);
    z(j+1) = cc(3) + (z(j)-cc(3))/((sqrt((x(j)-cc(1))^2+(y(j)-cc(2))^2+(z(j)-cc(3))^2))^2);
end


plot3(x,y,z,'.','MarkerSize',4) , hold on
stlwrite('test.stl',x, y, z);
```

Here is what the generated image looks like:

[image]

So far so good. The problem comes from the generated stl object.

[image]

At first I thought the problem is stlwrite function that I am using so I tried a different one - [sutf2stl](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/4512-surf2stl) but the problem is still the same. I will be grateful if anyone can point me to the right direction.

Best regards.